# In Scala project: How to add dependency Jar details into Manifest file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, classpath, manifest

I am new to Scala and i am writing simple file read & write (AWS S3) program from AWS using Scala. The below command is used to add jar details into Manifest file using Maven. Similarly, I need command/configuration for scala project to add jar details into Manifest file

```
<manifest>
     <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
     <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
     ...
```

build.sbt

```
enablePlugins(PackPlugin)
name := "FileReadAWS"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.4"
```

/project/plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.13")
```

When i execute `sbt pack` command and it is creating project jar & dependency jar added/downloaded into `<project ocation>\target\pack\lib`

**lib** folder contains project jar as well and it has Manifest file with Main class details and but doesnot have jar details

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: FileReadAWS
Implementation-Version: 0.1
Specification-Vendor: default
Specification-Title: FileReadAWS
Implementation-Vendor-Id: default
Specification-Version: 0.1
Implementation-Vendor: default
Main-Class: spark.file.io.FileReader
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a fat jar, have a look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly